# Alternative of Foreign Key in RDBMS

Tags: mysql, rdbms

I am studying database course now, and I know a foreign key is the primary key of other table. But I am curious about the presentation of relationship: if we don't use foreign key to link with other table, but use a function to map a primary key of a record from a table to another one, does it work? I think it works in theory, but I am not sure is good idea in reality. Is it reasonable?

P.S.
because I think a table is a set, a function is mapping method from a set to another.

Thanks in advance, 
Sincerely.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a primary key, your foreign key can map to other things

Comment: What does "use a function to map a primary key of a record from a table to another one" mean? What is your textbook name & edition? Your question uses terms strangely, please clarify. Please reference an authoritative presentation. PS PKs don't matter, CKs do. Relational terms don't mean the same as SQL terms. Are you asking about the relationl model or SQL? An SQL FK references a unique column set--that includes PKs. PKs, FKs & other constraints are not needed to record & query, they are for the DBMS to disallow invalid states.

Answer (score 4):

You don't *have* to define foreign keys in a MySQL database. In a query, you can use joins to define how relations should be fed into your query's result set.

There are good reasons to define foreign keys, though. Some of these are:

- Defining a foreign key creates an index on that column, influencing the way that the RDBMS stores its data, so that it can optimize queries for faster results;
- If you set a foreign key in MySQL, you can also define what happens to child records when the table containing the primary key is changed. Child records may, for example, be deleted automatically (a "cascading delete"). This is helpful for database integrity, as this avoids orphaned records in the child table. These cascades may go through several relationships levels.

Comment: The points raised are valid, but primarily a FOREIGN KEY is a constraint. It disallows values from being stored if those values don't appear in the referenced columns. It is principally a mechanism to enforce referential integrity in the database. Some RDBMS (including MySQL) require an appropriate index (on foreign key columns) so the constraint can be enforced. MySQL will automatically create a suitable index (if one does not already exist) when a foreign key constraint is declared. (Note that some RDBMS don't require an index, but that can have a significant adverse affect on performance.)

Comment: Constraints do not "define how relations should be fed into your query's result set". Constraints are not needed to query. They are for integrity. Table meanings are necessary & sufficient to query. Although when a constraint holds, certain expressions return the same results as others that otherwise wouldn't..

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is not clear. What question do you think you are answering & what meanings do you ascribe to words in the question post to justify that that's what it's asking?